# Table data structure for quick searching with wildcards

Tags: java, data-structures

I am storing a relatively small amount (perhaps may be larger in the future) and then searching it but this is proving to be a bit of a bottleneck in my project.

To expand I have up to a few thousand rows and a few columns. I wish to be able search with the ability to specify a simple match with match all wildcards for any element. All the insertion can take place at construction, ideally duplicates wouldn't exist and the amount of querying outweighs table construction quite considerably. I also need to be able to compare tables to see if the contain the same elements (differences between them aren't needed). Objects that are stored can be hashed but are not ordered. This is all stored in memory.

So initially I started with a simple hashset:

```
   Set<ArrayWrapper> data = new HashSet<ArrayWrapper>();
```

where `ArrayWrapper` is a simple wrapper for an `Object[]`. This obviously is slow for searching with wildcards, e.g. `{new Integer(3), null, "Test", null}` where `null` means match anything. I added an index for the least wildcarded value which helps but I feel there may be a better solution?

Comment: Can you give a small example of the table data and the searches you wanna do?

Comment: @the-alchemist This is part of the infrastructure for an interpreted language I have and therefore somewhat affected by the user. But the gist is I will end up with an array of objects where null means match anything and I need to find any matching row(s) within the table (which itself will be null free).

Comment: Have you considered using a small (in-memory) database and querying that?

Comment: @Bart K. I did consider it but couldn't think of anything that would be light enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Justin - building off you answer, I believe this could be implemented using map of maps. @Molehill - Is the number of keys used defined? or is it variable?

If it's defined (for example 3: Integer, String, String) you could do 
`Map<Integer, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>`. When you have a wild card in your search, then you would have to poll through the entire entrySet or value collection of the map that you're at. You could get fancy and write an abstraction around that though. I recently did this for a 2 key map.

Comment: It is all user defined but being an interpreter this isn't known until runtime. A map of maps may just do what I need. I shall try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The look-up isn't quite as fast as a hashset when you don't have any wildcards, but it allows wildcards and is still quite fast.